# VS 2019 SSIS - Unable to load a package due to error "The parameter is incorrect": CPackage::LoadFromXML fails

Tags: xml, ssis, visual-studio-2019

I am using VisualStudio 2019 with a SSIS project.

A package that I've worked on, worked OK, till suddenly I got an Error:

> Microsoft Visual Studio is unable to load this document: The package failed to load due to error 0x80070057 The parameter is incorrect.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.

ErrorDescription:
[image: ErrorDescription]
Now I can't open the package, or run it by a batch file.
There were no changes before it stopped working.

I checked the XML of the package - It is valid.

I removed the SSIS extension and re-install, didn't help.

What can I try more?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the log files.  There is a log file for SSIS under the application in the START Button.  SQL Server Management Studio using the explorer there is a log file under Management.

Comment: Log of VS or SSMS? I am using VS2019, and SSMS is not installed on this server.

Comment: SSMS only need to be installed on local machine.  Once SSMS is installed on a machine it can connect to a Server on any other machine.  You do not need SSMS to be installed on same machine as the server.  Just need the credentials to be recognized over the network.  SSMS uses Windows Credentials.  So if you client can connect to the server than SSMS can also connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem caused by git-merge.
When I have turn to the original branch (with the changes) - It worked.